# How to properly setup sockets using vapor

Tags: swift, websocket, vapor

I am woking on a web socket app using vapor. I am new to using vapor and server side code in general. Right now I am putting all my main code in the main.swift file in the run folder

Here is my code:

```
let config = try Config()
try config.setup()
let drop = try Droplet(config)
try drop.setup()

var instance = [(socket: WebSocket, uuid: String)]()

drop.socket("log") { req, ws in
    background {
        while ws.state == .open {
            try? ws.ping()
            drop.console.wait(seconds: 10) // every 10 seconds
       }
    }

    ws.onText = { ws, text in
        //print ("log is \(text)")
        //This is where my code is about to handle data sent and received by the socket. 
        let logMessage:JSON = try JSON(bytes: text.utf8.array)

        guard logMessage != nil else {try ws.send("issue with json"); return}
        if logMessage == "pair" {
            instance.append((ws, "383485838498"))
        }else if logMessage == "message" {
            for sock in instance {
                //send data to all saved socket instances 
            }
        }
    }

    ws.onClose = { ws, _, _, _ in
        print ("log sokcet closeing?")
        try ws.send("log socket closed")
    }
}
```

I am saving all my instances of the socket in a local variable called `instance` above. Then I am sending data as it is received from another socket to those saved instances. I have a feeling I am doing things completely wrong but for now this is working. Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way to do it?

Instead of using an array of type: `(socket: WebSocket, uuid: String)` I want to use an array of type `Instance`, the struct that I have defined below. Right now I can't because it says Use of undeclared type 'Instance'. I wanted to use something like this `let app = Application()` but again, it give me this issue:  `Use of unresolved identifier 'Application'`.

Here is the struct I want to use

```
struct Instance {
    var socket:WebSocket?
    var uuid:String?
}
```